# How do I fix this error I get when trying to run DS9?

Tags: 11.10, shared-library

```
ds9: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Please help to fix the error.

My ds9 is in `/usr/local/bin/ds9`

Answer (score 3):

### Problem summary

This indicates that a certain file (namely, "*libXss.so.1*") is missing for DS9 to work.

### How to solve problems like this on your own

To find out which package provides (or contains) a certain file in Ubuntu, you can use the "**apt-file**" command.

First, make sure "*apt-file*" is installed.

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

Now, using "*apt-file*" is simple enough.

```
apt-file search filename-to-search.for
```

This outputs a list of packages that provide a file named "*filename-to-search.for*", thus allowing you to install the necessary package(s) using apt-get.

### Real-life answer

In your case, you would need to run the following command:

```
apt-file search libXss.so.1
```

This outputs the following:

```
libxss1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1
libxss1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1.0.0
libxss1-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1.0.0
```

This indicates that the package you need to install in this specific case is most likely "**libxss1**".

So, to install it, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1
```

Now, try running DS9 again, and you should find that the error message is now gone.